# Fill the empty tag excerpts

Tags: discussion, tagging, tagwiki

[This post is basically a copy of a [similar post at meta.sf](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10144/3253).]

Tag excerpts are very useful. They provide a brief “[elevator pitch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)” for a tag, explaining the meaning for those unfamiliar with a series. At least as important, excerpts and wikis can also help clarify the usage of tags, particularly those that tend to be used incorrectly, e.g. frozen, aliens, or humans.

As of this post, though, nearly 600 tags lack both tag wikis and tag excerpts! A query (updated only once a week) to show how many can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/445925/most-common-tags-with-short-long-or-missing-excerpt-or-wiki?MaxBodyLength=0&MaxExcerptLength=1&MinBodyLength=-1&MinExcerptLength=-1&PlotMinimum=1&Bin=1&BinCount=20). I know that somewhere here we have an expert for every tag, whether they have 2 reputation or 200,000: someone who can provide a well-written, original tag excerpt or tag wiki for a tag that was previously forlorn and undescribed.

There are benefits to editing tag wikis:

- If you have less than 20,000 reputation, as do most people on this site, and you create a tag wiki (which requires approval), you will get a nice shiny +2 reputation. What’s more, tag wikis and tag excerpts count as separate posts.
- If you have more than 20,000 reputation, you can edit tag wikis freely. You might also progress toward [any](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/tag-editor) [of](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/150/research-assistant) [several](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) [badges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor).

Questions and answers are the lifeblood of this site, but the little things that hang around the periphery are important too! **This month, in the spirit of Answer the Unanswered Questions, let’s try to provide tag excerpts (and when needed, wikis) for as many of those blank tags as we can.**

Guidelines for writing tag excerpts are [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts). And, although it is not mentioned there, a tag wiki and excerpt **should be *original*: no Wikipedia lifting!**

Comment: I just added both for a tag yesterday :-) But apparently this is one of many.

Comment: A few tags are typos, or by other means not needed at all. Or should by synonyms to another. Maybe we should work on that too.

Comment: What is the difference between a `tag wiki` a `tag excerpt` and a `tag wiki excerpt`?

Comment: @cfr: Fixed. Thanks.